# Comparing dimensions in druid

Tags: druid

I recently started experimenting with druid. I have a use case which I'm not able to solve. I have 3 date columns primary_date, date_1 and date_2, amount and client.

I wanted to calulate sum(amount) when date_1 > date_2 when granularity is month. I wanted to calculate this for each month in 6 month interval for each client.

I also wanted to calcutate sum(amount) when date_1 > max(bucket date) for each bucket for 6 months for each client.

```
{
    "queryType" : "groupBy",
    "dataSource" : "data_source_xxx",
    "granularity" : "month",
    "dimensions" : ["client"],
    "intervals": ["2019-01-01/2019-07-01"],
    "aggregations":[{"type": "doubleSum", "name": "total_amount", "fieldName": "amount"}],
    "filter" : { 
        "type": "select",
        "dimension": "client",
        "value": "client" 
    }   
}
```

I wanted to modify the above query to have additional filters I have mentioned.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can realize this by using a virtual column, which does the date comparison. Then you should be able to use the virtual column in a filtered aggregation, which only applies the aggregation if the filter matches.

This is not tested, but I think something like this should work:

```
{
    "queryType": "groupBy",
    "dataSource": "data_source_xxx",
    "intervals": [
        "2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z/2019-07-01T00:00:00.000Z"
    ],
    "dimensions": [
        {
            "type": "default",
            "dimension": "client",
            "outputType": "string",
            "outputName": "client"
        }
    ],
    "granularity": "month",
    "aggregations": [
        {
            "type": "filtered",
            "filter": {
                "type": "selector",
                "dimension": "isOlder",
                "value": "1"
            },
            "aggregator": {
                "type": "doubleSum",
                "name": "sumAmount",
                "fieldName": "amount"
            }
        }
    ],
    "virtualColumns": [
        {
            "type": "expression",
            "name": "isOlder",
            "expression": "if( date_1 > date_2, '1', '0')",
            "outputType": "string"
        }
    ],
    "context": {
        "groupByStrategy": "v2"
    }
}
```

I have created this using this PHP code using this package: https://github.com/level23/druid-client

```
$client = new DruidClient(['router_url' => 'http://127.0.0.1:8888']);

// Build a select query
$builder = $client->query('data_source_xxx', Granularity::MONTH)
    ->interval("2019-01-01/2019-07-01")
    ->select(['client'])
    ->virtualColumn("if( date_1 > date_2, '1', '0')", 'isOlder')
    ->sum('amount', 'sumAmount', DataType::DOUBLE, function(FilterBuilder $filterBuilder){
        $filterBuilder->where('isOlder', '=', '1');
    });

echo $builder->toJson();
```